# Bookmarks syncing between 2 machines in Google Chrome after Time Machine Migration

Tags: time-machine, google-chrome, bookmarks, google-sync

I migrated from one Mac to another via Time Machine. So, I get a full copy of my system.

Now I'm using both of this Mac's. In Chrome logged-in by Google account and set up bookmarks synchronisation.

But in bookmarks bar I see all devices except my second mac. Probably Chrome somehow not recognise, that it the other Mac.

I tried delete app, but it doesn't help.

Who knows how to get around this problem?

---

**UPD:**

At first time both computers have the same name. 
But after renaming problems remained.

Comment: Maybe the bookmarks are in conflict because of your computer names? Do you have the ability to see the names of computers registered with your Google Account? I am thinking of Dropbox or iTunes which shows a list of all computers (and their names) registered with the account)

Comment: Yep! This is the first thing, that I do. Now they have 2 different names.

Comment: The same problem was described on this topic: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/hWXasiDrjS8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*In a nutshell it caused by Chrome don't do any checks "is it new computer or not".*

So, you should do 2 steps:

1. Rename new mac to unique name. (**Preferences -> Sharing -> Computer Name**)
2. Delete Chrome data file on new computer.

**For me (on 10.9.2) this command works well:**

`rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome`

**Be careful** if your important data (history, passwords, bookmarks) not stored in google account.

Since all my user-sensentive data stored in google account it's safety.

Answer (score 2):

Then my only thought remaining is that by doing a direct transfer of all files that there is a special chrome ID/profile that gets created when the app opens the first time. If that file gets copied then both computer have the same profile. You might have to export the bookmarks in chrome on one computer an then delete the `~/Library/Application Support/Chrome` folder and then `~/Library/Preferences/com.google.Chrome.plist` file in Preferences. Relaunch Chrome and that should force an ID/profile creation and then you could sync again.

Comment: I tried this out and it worked.
You don't need to export bookmarks, since they're synchronized. However, you might want to move away those files, instead of deleting them, in case something goes lost. In my case, this allowed restoring the database of the Session Buddy extension - that extension datas are not synced is a huge limitation of Chrome Sync.

Comment: I can't find `plist` file and you forgot Google folder in your address. And address should be `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome` (OS 10.9.2)

Comment: Seeing as how I wrote this 4 months ago on 10.8.5 I don't feel sorry there being differences. Glad you figured it out yourself though.